# Adding items to VB.NET ListView and having them shown in the order they were added

Tags: vb.net, image, sorting, listview

I am creating an app launcher - that is basically a ListView with a "group" of shortcuts files ( ie images associated with a shortcut and the text is the name of the shortcut ) in it.  It's all been working fine and dandy, except this last thing that I want to do.  The apps that appear in the listview are stored in an xml file and what I'm trying to do is add the apps into the listview in the order they appear in the xml file i.e. this probably won't be alphabetical.

So I read an app name from the xml file, find it's shortcut lnk file, extract the icon from the file and add it to the Listview; using:

```
lvPrograms.LargeImageList = ProgramIcons

Dim item As ListViewItem

Dim FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(shortcutFile.Name)

item = New ListViewItem(FileName, 1)
item.ImageKey = FileName
iconFile = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(shortcutFile.FullName)

ProgramIcons.Images.Add(FileName, iconFile)
lvPrograms.Items.Add(item)
```

I also set the Sorting property of the listView to None

When the code has added all the apps, I was hoping for them to appear in the order I added them, but it just seems to add them in a random order ie.. not my order or ascending or descending ?!

If I check the contents of lvPrograms.Items(X).Text in the debug window, then (0) is not the first one I added and (6) is not the seventh one I added ?!

Hope this makes sense and someone could help me get the apps listed in the order that I added them ?

Cheers,

Chris.

Extra Info asked for my Plutonix:

Basically my xml is read into an object called UserAppSettings which has a collection of Application objects and their Name property if the name of the app.  Also the ProgramDetails is a structure that holds various properties about a shortcut - name, working folder etc

The image lists (in case relevant are 32bit & 16bit in depth )

```
    lvPrograms.Clear()
    ProgramIcons.Images.Clear()
    ProgramIconsSmall.Images.Clear()

    lvPrograms.LargeImageList = ProgramIcons
    lvPrograms.SmallImageList = ProgramIconsSmall


    Dim dir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(userShortcutsFolder)

    lvPrograms.BeginUpdate()
    lvPrograms.Sorting = SortOrder.None

    Dim shortcutFile As FileInfo

    For Each AppToShow As Application In UserAppSettings.Applications
        shortcutFile = New FileInfo(userShortcutsFolder + AppToShow.Name + ".lnk")
        addShortcutToListView(shortcutFile)
    Next


    Private Sub addShortcutToListView(shortcutFile As FileInfo)

    Dim CurrentProgram As ProgramDetails
    Dim item As ListViewItem

    CurrentProgram = New ProgramDetails
    With CurrentProgram
        .FullName = shortcutFile.FullName
        .Name = shortcutFile.Name
        .NameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(shortcutFile.Name)

        item = New ListViewItem(.NameWithoutExtension, 1)
        .Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(.FullName)

        getShortcutProperties(CurrentProgram)

        ProgramIcons.Images.Add(.NameWithoutExtension, .Icon)
        ProgramIconsSmall.Images.Add(.NameWithoutExtension, .Icon)

        item.ImageKey = .NameWithoutExtension
    End With

    item.Tag = CurrentProgram

    lvPrograms.Items.Add(item)
    '   MsgBox(item.Text + vbNewLine + lvPrograms.Items(lvPrograms.Items.Count - 1).Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try something for me?.. after lvPrograms.items.add(item), add this line of code.... msgbox(item & vbnewline & lvPrograms.items(lvPrograms.items.count - 1).value ... and let it run through the entire process to see if the items are being entered in correctly or if they are being sorted at runtime.

Comment: they are not being sorted at run time - you need to use the Sort method for that.  What is the LV's View?

Comment: Thanks for the replies: - the listView's view is LargeIcon (but tried with list and makes no difference)

Comment: Nefariis - I entered the line you suggested as MsgBox(item.Text + vbNewLine + lvPrograms.Items(lvPrograms.Items.Count - 1).Text) and added 4 files to my xml in the order of App3, App2, App1 & App4.  The result of the msgbox was - "App3 + App3", "App2 + App2", "App1 + App1", "App4 + App1" and the order they appeared was actually App4,3,2,1

Comment: please show you actual loop

Comment: Added loop ( & a bit more ) to original question, as it seemed easier to add code in that section ?!

Comment: Sorry if I've wasted folks time - but I've just gone thru my code and commented out every line that does anything with the view property or sortorder property of the listview (virtually half of my code :)) and it is now displaying the apps in the correct order !!  So now (or rather tomorrow, after a good nights kip) gotta find out which line(s) were causing my problem.  Thanks again for everyone who tried to help.